# getWindowHandles().size() returning incorrect value

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am using Windows 8, IE 11 with any version of IEDriverSever.

getWindowHandles().size() returns incorrect size. If
the number of open windows is 2, the getWindowHandles().size() returning 1.

As suggested, I am attaching my code with this.

```html
public class TIEBrowser {
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
  
  
  DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
  dc.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.
      INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);

   
  System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", "C:\\Selenium\\IEDriverServer\\IEDriverServer.exe");
  WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(dc);
    
  String baseUrl = "http://10.72.139.159:8080/krsnsys/";
                
  driver.navigate().to(baseUrl);
  
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
        
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle()+" -1- ");
        
        WebElement myElement = driver.findElement(By.id("username-id"));
        myElement.sendKeys("silk1");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.name("login")).click();
                
        driver.switchTo();
                
        String NewInteraction = "html/body/div[1]/div[5]/div[2]/div/div/div[5]/fieldset/div/div/div/div/div[1]/fieldset/div/a[1]/div/img";
        WebElement link = driver.findElement(By.xpath(NewInteraction));
        
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 120);// 1 minute 
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(NewInteraction)));
                       
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle()+" -2- ");
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        
        String handle= driver.getWindowHandle();
        System.out.println(handle);
        link.click();
               
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        System.out.println(handle);
        
        Set<String> handles =  driver.getWindowHandles();
        **System.out.println(handles.size());**
        for(String windowHandle  : handles)
            {
            System.out.println(windowHandle);
         if(!windowHandle.equals(handle))
               {
               driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
               System.out.println(windowHandle);
               }
            }
               
           System.out.println(handle);
           driver.manage().window().maximize();
           Thread.sleep(2000);
```

Comment: Please Add a snippet of your code will help us with identifying why the statement returns 1 instead of 2 Windows. Could have something to do with when the line of code is executed.